# Render Swagger UI output?

Tags: 7, javascript

Is it possible to render Swagger UI output in Drupal? I'd like something similar to this example in the content area of a page:
http://petstore.swagger.io/

I've tried two "in progress" modules without much luck (mmillford's Swagger module and the tpanagos SwaggerUI module). Both are producing no output (blank pages) when following the included instructions.